# Return child nodes under different parents who have same name

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data:

```
 Parent Id=11
     Child Name=A1

 Parent Id=22
     Child Name=A1
     Child Name=B2
```

Using LINQ, I want all child nodes who have a same name and their parent id like below:

```
 11, A1
 22, A1
```

This is the structure of parent and child nested class that I created:

```
public class cParent
{
    public List<ChildClass> listChildClass;
    public string parentId { get; set; } 
}

public class ChildClass
{
    public string childNAme{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 11 and 22 aren't the same as A1. What are you trying to say?

Comment: As an aside, it would also really help if you could use conventional names, following normal .NET conventions.

Comment: If you want the all parent id of the child's then apply the `group by` .

Comment: @JLRishe Here, A1 is a child under 2 parents, whose IDs are 11 and 22. I want the list of children who share same name but fall under different parents, in this case the end result will be: 
 11  A1 and 22  A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use grouping to look for duplicates:

```
var p11 = new cParent { parentId = "11" }; // assuming listChildClass is a collection
p11.listChildClass.Add(new ChildClass { childNAme = "A1" });

var p22 = new cParent { parentId = "22" };
p22.listChildClass.Add(new ChildClass { childNAme = "A1" });
p22.listChildClass.Add(new ChildClass { childNAme = "B2" });

var parents = new List<cParent> { p11, p22 };

var duplicatesByKey =
    from parent in parents
    from child in parent.listChildClass
    let combo = new { parent.parentId, child.childNAme }
    group combo by combo.childNAme into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select new { g.Key, Values = g.ToList() };
```

This would work even better if you would implement comparators, but I'll leave that up to the reader.

Comment: Thanks @Caramiriel, it works. But what do you mean by comparators? As I am new to LINQ , would be nice if you could give a clue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on the child object, so that you can check for equality. Now we just get around it by comparing the text (name of the child), which happens to be `string` and includes its own implementation of equality.